# Remove passive event handler for `wheel` & `scroll` events

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events

I'm having an issue trying to control `scroll` and `wheel` events.

Currently I can stop them by adding event listeners to the `window` object for those specific events but their handlers require deactivating `passive` to work. This causes an issue when trying to remove them because `passive` doesn't seem to exist on "remove" eventHandlers and the browser doesn't seem to remove the right event handler. [Here's a link to a reproducible example](https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolling-hook-gp04m) as well as the code to the hook I'm using below

Anyone have any good solutions or workarounds to this? Most of the related questions didn't seem to have very good (or current) answers dealing with the recent browser update to allow passive events

```
const useControlScrolling = (pauseScroll: boolean): void => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const preventScroll = (e: Event) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    };
    const eventOpts = {
      passive: false
    };
    const disableScrolling = () => {
      console.log("disabling scroll");

      // I add the passive prop to the allow `preventDefault` to work
      window.addEventListener("wheel", preventScroll, eventOpts); 
      window.addEventListener("scroll", preventScroll, eventOpts); 
    };

    const enableScrolling = () => {
      console.log("enabling scroll");

      // the remove handler doesn't allow the eventOpts so it doesn't know which handler to remove. Casting it does not help
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", preventScroll); 
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", preventScroll);
    };

    if (pauseScroll) {
      disableScrolling();
    } else {
      enableScrolling();
    }
  }, [pauseScroll]);
};

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  useControlScroll(visible);

  window.addEventListener("click", () => setVisible(!visible));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time when you call the `useControlScrolling`, it will create a new `preventScroll` function with same code and name. However, it is not the same function as previous created. Therefore, when you pass `preventScroll` into `removeEventListener`, it will not find the exact same function. So the function will not be removed.

In order to make this work, you can move the `preventScroll` out of `useControlScrolling` to make it consistant for every function call.